# echarts4r multiple axis on different grids

Tags: yaxis, echarts4r

I would like to get a chart with 2 grids. One with two y axis.
**a** and **b** on one graph with 2 y axis and **c**,**d**,and **e** on another grid.
I tried to number them from 0,1 and 2, but it doesn't work. I would need to add an Y axis as on the picture below [image]
Thanks

```
 df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  a = runif(20, 10, 100),
  b = runif(20, 10, 1000),
  c= runif(20, 10, 300),
  d = runif(20, 10, 300),
  e= runif(20, 10, 300)
)


df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_line(a,x_index = 0, y_index = 0) |>
  e_line(b,x_index = 0, y_index = 0) |>
  e_bar(c, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  e_bar(d, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  e_bar(e, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  # e_bar(H1N1pdm, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  # e_bar(Flu_B_Victoria, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  # e_bar(H1N1pdm_Flu_B, stack = "grp",x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |>
  e_grid(height = "25%") |> 
  e_grid(height = "25%", top = "50%") |>
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1) |>
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1) |>
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") |>
  e_datazoom(x_index = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: ok. I managed to do it by changing the order of the plot, starting from the e_bar and then the e_line. It works, but don't get why.